# Android How to let load data from firebase database combine with orderByChild() & startAt() & limitToFirst()?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to sort the data from Firebase RealTimeDatabase. What I am trying to do is when I load the data first, it will start from the child value I put inside like "7", then it will sort the data base on the child "NUMBER" value in an ascending sequence and limitToFirst(2) data. But the log always show that the dataSnapshot does not exist.

Here is my code

> Code for loading data

```
private void testData(){
        final ArrayList<FirebaseDatabaseGetSet> testArrayList;
        testArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
        databaseReference.child("VTEST").orderByChild("NUMBER").startAt("7").limitToFirst(2).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                    Log.d("MOSTPOPCURRENTLASTNODE", "LOAINGMOREDATA");
                    for (DataSnapshot DS:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        FirebaseDatabaseGetSet getSet = DS.getValue(FirebaseDatabaseGetSet.class);
                        testArrayList.add(getSet);
                    }
                    Log.d("MOSTPOPCURRENTLASTNODE", String.valueOf(testArrayList.get(0).getNUMBER()));
                    Log.d("MOSTPOPCURRENTLASTNODE", String.valueOf(testArrayList.get(1).getNUMBER()));

                }else {
                    Log.d("MOSTPOPCURRENTLASTNODE", "NOLOAINGMOREDATA");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

and here is my Firebase data structure

> Data Structure

```
"VTEST" : {
"A" : {
  "NUMBER" : 5
},
"B" : {
  "NUMBER" : 3
},
"C" : {
  "NUMBER" : 7
},
"D" : {
  "NUMBER" : 10
},
"E" : {
  "NUMBER" : 12
},
"F" : {
  "NUMBER" : 8
}
```

}

What I expect from the log is "7" & "8", but it always show the dataSnapshot does not exist. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong in here, I had try to look for some others similar questions already, but could not find any solution for this.

Comment: Can you replace the data structure with the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated my data structure with JSON already

Comment: @GAMETTXD Why do you say you aren't getting the data? How/where do you verify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're filtering by:

```
databaseReference.child("VTEST").orderByChild("NUMBER").startAt("7")
```

And you're storing:

```
"NUMBER" : 7
```

If you look carefully you'll see that one is a string, and the other is an integer. And in the Firebase Realtime Database values of different types are never equal.

To fix the problem, filter by a numeric value:

```
databaseReference.child("VTEST").orderByChild("NUMBER").startAt(7)
```

Comment: @ FrankvanPuffelen You saved my life, It works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try this i am getting data this way by shorting it child:-

```
mChatReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(VTEST)
                .child("user id");
        Query query = mChatReference.orderByChild("NUMBER");
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                yourList.add(snapshot.child("NUMBER").getValue());
            }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: i am updating my answer